# SparkLauncher Stand Alone Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone, spark-launcher

Using Java API, I'm able to submit, getStatus & kill spark applications submitted via Spark Launcher in 'client' mode. Can Spark Launcher track & control applications submitted in Standalone 'cluster' mode?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Standalone Cluster as YARN Cluster? If yes, Then Spark track and control application. You can view logs using Yarn logs -applicationId

Comment: Spark Standalone cluster. Not with YARN. I was wondering if Spark Launcher Java API can control spark applications submitted with deploy_mode=cluster